# Rhino - Passing a javascript object to java

Tags: java, javascript, object, rhino

Im quite new to Rhino and my question is around how to achieve the following,

Say I have a javascript object that follows something like the following that I can consume within java.

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.string1 = "Hello";
myObject.string2 = "World";
myObject.int1 = 1;
```

But how do I consume this within java if its dynamic. For .e.g. if you decide to add few more members dynamically to this object within javascript. Is this doable ? My guess is the class defined within java will have to take all the possible members into account to do this ?

Hopefully I have explained what im trying to achieve correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript objects, when you access them in Java, are all essentially the same class: `ScriptableObject` which implements the `Scriptable` interface [(GitHub source)](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Scriptable.java). There are a few other classes for functions and other specialized objects.

The `Scriptable` interface includes methods like `get`, `has`, and `put` that correspond roughly to `myObject.string1`, `myObject.hasOwnProperty("string1")`, and `myObject.string1 = "Hello"` in JavaScript. The `ScriptableObject` class adds some other useful methods for defining properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a library like GSON for converting a javascript object to JAVA.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

you can convert a javascript object to JSON using JSON.stringify

and then use GSON or another such library to generate a Java object.